# android trigger another project activity

Tags: android, android-activity

This problem freak me out

I have an application and now i want to transer data between client android application and localhost tomcat 7 server, i did that many times ago, now when i want to send data from client to server it works well and i can see the data on the server, but something happend and the android application is trying to trigger an activity from another project i deleted that project then still try to trigger activty form another project

my actiivty name is "Signup", and the android client trying to trigger activiteis with the same name from another projects.

Comment: You have multiple problems.  One at a time.  First problem.   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-02 03:33:25.794: E/AndroidRuntime(278): java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '[Lorg.apache.http.Header;@44ee4c10' as integer, at this line at com.Syriatel.EatTel.Signup$1.onItemSelected(Signup.java:88).  What is numberofcities value?

Comment: check my last note please, for `come.Syriatel.EatTel.Signup` it goes to another activity on another project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as in log :

> NumberFormatException: unable to parse
>   '[Lorg.apache.http.Header;@44ee4c10' as integer

means you are trying to parse wrong string to Integer . wrap casting code inside try/catch block to avoid `NumberFormatException` as :

```
String str_NumberOfCities="";
 Header[] headers = response.getAllHeaders();
  for (int i=0; i < headers.length; i++) {
         Header h = headers[i];
          Log.i(TAG, "Header names: "+h.getName());
          if(h.getName().toLowerCase().contains("NumberOfCities".toLowerCase()){
                str_NumberOfCities=h.getValue();
           }
      Log.i(TAG, "Header Value: "+h.getValue());
  }
int numberOfCities=0;
 try {
       numberOfCities = Integer.parseInt(str_NumberOfCities);
   } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
       numberOfCities=0;
    }
Data.cities = new String[numberOfCities];
///....your code
```

Comment: i know this, but it goes to another activity , and please check my last note, i will also try to comment the `numberofcitties` and will tell you what is happend

Comment: you right , when i comment the `numberofcities` no exception happend, check my edit please i will tell you the server code , maybe the wrong in it

Comment: @FernadoMargin : where is Signup.java:88 line ?

Comment: `int numberOfCities = Integer.parseInt(response
        .getHeaders("NumberOfCities").toString());` this is the line 88

Comment: check my server code please ,when i comment the line 88 , no exception happpend, it seems like there is wrong on server, right?

Comment: @FernadoMargin : just do one test put  `Header[] headers = response.getAllHeaders();
  for (int i=0; i < headers.length; i++) {
            Header h = headers[i];
            Log.i(TAG, "Header names: "+h.getName());
            Log.i(TAG, "Header Value: "+h.getValue());
 }`  in place of `int numberOfCities = Integer.parseInt(response .getHeaders("NumberOfCities").toString());` and check logcat you are getting NumberOfCities Header Name or Value in log ?

Comment: `TAG` is not recoginzed by eclipes, can i put instread of it what?

Comment: @FernadoMargin : friend just put any String like Activity name as  `Log.i("Your_Activity_Name", "Header Value: "+h.getValue());`

Comment: no error happend, it give me green things on logcat, i will put that green things on the edited questoni

Comment: @FernadoMargin : ok put it

Comment: i changed the names of `TAG` to this `Log.i("name", "Header names: " + h.getName());
       Log.i("value", "Header Value: " + h.getValue());`

Comment: @FernadoMargin : just copy paste my edit answer and let me known it's working ?

Comment: YOU ARE AMMMMMMMMMMAZING , IT WORKS MY FIREND , THAAAANK YOU